# Scrolling the list view to the desired result position

Tags: android, listview, search, scroll

When I try searching the list view it should scroll to the obtained result instead of filtering the content. For example if I type "De" it should scroll to the first item in the list that matched the Char sequence "De" not filter the items that match the sequence.

Comment: Please provide additional details and show what you already have implemented. If you already know how to implement a `Filter`, that's helpful information.

Comment: If list is getting Filtered, then you have the desired available item on screen. what else you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the place where the Charecter sequence (in your case DE) is available.

Then scrol the ListView by calling

```
listView.setSelection(position);
```